# Python Beautifulsoup get href from inner tag in browser bookmark html

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want program to read bookmark.html that export from firefox

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time, re

f = open(r'D:/TestCode/bookmarks.html','r',encoding="utf8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),"lxml")
f.close()
dl = []
for i in soup.findAll("dl"):
    dl.append(i)

for j in range(len(dl)):
    if dl[j].contents[0].has_attr('href') and dl[j].contents[0].has_attr('add_date'):
        uri =  dl[j].contents[0]['href']
        print(uri)
```

This is some example of firefox export bookmark

```
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<!-- This is an automatically generated file.
     It will be read and overwritten.
     DO NOT EDIT! -->
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
<H1>bookmark menu</H1>
<DL><p>
    <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1517201918" LAST_MODIFIED="1550415410">Mozilla Firefox</H3>
    <DL><p>
        <DT><A HREF="https://support.mozilla.org/th/products/firefox" ADD_DATE="1545397135" LAST_MODIFIED="1545397135">help</A>
    </DL><p>
<DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1395221079" LAST_MODIFIED="1550979714">Other</H3>
    <DL><p>
        <DT>...
    </DL>
.
.
.
.
    <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1561105535" LAST_MODIFIED="1561113405">importMobile</H3>
    <DL><p>
        <DT><A HREF="need this" ADD_DATE="1549779806" LAST_MODIFIED="1561113405"></A>
        <DT><A HREF="need this" ADD_DATE="1551437973" LAST_MODIFIED="1561113405"></A>
        <DT><A HREF="need this" ADD_DATE="1552966401" LAST_MODIFIED="1561113405"></A>
    </DL><p>
.
.
.
</DL>
```

I try to get href under folder importMobile but it return 
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'has_attr'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css selector to search anchor tag with attribute.this should give you expected result.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data='''<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<!-- This is an automatically generated file.
     It will be read and overwritten.
     DO NOT EDIT! -->
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
<H1>bookmark menu</H1>
<DL><p>
    <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1517201918" LAST_MODIFIED="1550415410">Mozilla Firefox</H3>
    <DL><p>
        <DT><A HREF="https://support.mozilla.org/th/products/firefox" ADD_DATE="1545397135" LAST_MODIFIED="1545397135">help</A>
    </DL><p>
<DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1395221079" LAST_MODIFIED="1550979714">Other</H3>
    <DL><p>
        <DT>...
    </DL>
.
.
.
.
    <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1561105535" LAST_MODIFIED="1561113405">importMobile</H3>
    <DL><p>
        <DT><A HREF="need this" ADD_DATE="1549779806" LAST_MODIFIED="1561113405"></A>
        <DT><A HREF="need this" ADD_DATE="1551437973" LAST_MODIFIED="1561113405"></A>
        <DT><A HREF="need this" ADD_DATE="1552966401" LAST_MODIFIED="1561113405"></A>
    </DL><p>
.
.
.
</DL>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
item=soup.find_all('dl')[3]

for tag in item.select('a[href][add_date]'):
    print(tag['href'])
```

### OutPut

```
need this
need this
need this
```

Answer (score 1):

Check all dt who has attribute `a` and `add_date` like this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


f = open(r'abc.html') #Change with your path
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),"lxml")

f.close()


dl = soup.findAll("dt")


for j in dl:

    if j.find('a') != None and j.find('a')['add_date'] != None :

       uri = j.find('a')['href']
       print uri
```

Output:

```
https://support.mozilla.org/th/products/firefox
need this
need this
need this
```